# CFRunLoopRunInMode freeze in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Hello I have a problem with `UITableView` freeze,

"downloadItem" below gets called when someone clicks on a button on the iPad. Its supposed to download a file and then return.

During the download, while stuck in that function, I want the UI to still be responsive, so I installed a runloop like below.

The actual downloadItem function is WAY more complicated than shown below, but what is shown is the basic idea of it. I know this isn't the best way, but for other reasons, I can't change it at this time, especially due to the existing complexity of the actual function.

The problem is that I also have a `UITableView` on the screen (as well as the button), if the `UITableView` is clicked or scrolled while in this function, in the runloop, the `UITableView` sometimes freezes up, and remains frozen even after exiting this function. This doesn't happen every time for some reason, maybe 40% of the time.

Does anyone know how to fix, is the RunLoop call below done right? Why when I click on the `UITableView` while in the runloop below, the table sometimes freezes up?

```
-(IBAction) downloadItem
{
    BOOL downloading=TRUE;
    callFunctionsToStartdownload(...);
    while (downloading) {
        downloading=DownloadSomeBytes(...);  
        CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 0, YES);
    }
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, this seems unnecessary. You want the *processing* of downloaded bytes to be in a thread (which this does not address), but the actual asynchronous NSURLConnection should do its work in a thread (and then calls back to the thread that started it).

Comment: I just wanted to know why the UITableview freeze up sometimes if clicked or scrolled while in downloadItem.

Comment: Been a while since I dug into run loop stuff (since it's rarely needed), but you must be blocking the UI thread. What does DownloadSomeBytes do?